# git: best strategy to merge secondary branch

Tags: git

Sometimes, when I am developing a big feature, I create a secondary branch (out of my original feature branch) to make it easier for my colleagues (and for myself sometimes) to visualize differences between parts of the same feature. It should look like this:

```
main      --o--o--o---------
                \
feature          o--o--o--o--o
                        \
secondary                o--o--o
```

When I need to merge everything, I usually merge *secondary* on *feature* and then to *main*, which works just fine. The problem is that sometimes I need to "merge by steps", meaning that I cannot merge *secondary* into *feature, but I have to merge *feature* into *main*, first. In that case, when I update *secondary* with everything new in *main*, it messes it up a bit, like having conflict in most files modified on both *feature* and *secondary*.

What should be the best approach to not mess this up?

P.D.: this may be a common question, but searching I couldn't put it to words to find a similar question :(

Comment: Are `feature` and `secondary` alternative implementations of the same feature, or is `secondary` an independent development that happens to share some commits with `feature` because it is convenient?

Answer (score 1):

You should rebase the `secondary` branch in your then-feature-merged `main` branch.

In that way you will be kept with only modifications done on you `secondary` branch which are not already in the `feature` or `main` branches.

You could still have conflict, but only on modifications done specifically in your `secondary` branch so it should be easy to fix.

Summary:

- `git switch main`
- `git merge feature`
- `git switch secondary`
- `git rebase main` + any commands to solve conflit and ends rebase
- `git switch main`
- `git merge secondary` (add `--no-ff` if you want to keep a merge commit)